# React router site not working after deploying

Tags: reactjs, github, react-router

I'm trying to deploy my react-router site on GitHub pages, but every time I deploy, my build gets failed, and the link it generates only shows my `header` and `footer`, which displays on every route.

On local, it works perfectly well.

```
const App = () => {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter basename='/utah-jazz-project'>
          <Header />
          <ScrollToTop>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Section1PS />}></Route>
              <Route path="/ebs" element={<Section1EBS />}></Route>
            </Routes>
          </ScrollToTop>
          <Footer />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
   );
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "homepage": "http://{username}.github.io/utah-jazz-project", // I have replaced with my username
  "name": "utah-jazz-project",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
}
```

The error I'm getting on Github Pages:

```
Error: Error: Request failed with status code 502
{"message":"Server Error"}
```

I have tried deploying on vercel as well, and over there, it gives me the blank page. So I guess it might not be the GitHub pages, but the problem with react-router?

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe github works with hash routers. See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

Comment: @DrewReese thank you. Really appreciate it!